# How can I change the label associated with a digital certificate without using 'ikeyman' tool.

Tags: ibm-mq

I created a keydatabase and added the public certificate signed by a CA. I need to change the label of this certificate. I can do it using the ikeyman tool. Is there any command to do that?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the runmqakm utility to rename a label. See the sample command below where

-label -> Current lable

-new-lable - New lable

```
runmqakm -cert -rename -db C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\SSLQM\ssl\sslqm.kdb -pw passw0rd -label TestCert -new-label MQCERT
```